# In Explorer, after performing factory reset Google play store converted to Market place

Tags: google-play-store, factory-reset, htc-explorer

I performed factory data reset of my another device "HTC Explorer". And before performing the reset Play store was there but now it disappears, and instead of play store now its Market place. So how to convert Market place to Google Play Store again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Play was formerly Android Market. Your phone would originally have had Android Market (I am assuming its an old one, probably Gingerbread). When you did a factory reset all the updates were reverted back included on Android Market (aka Google Play).

Android Market automatically updates itself so give it some time and it should update itself to Google Play.

Comment: Ya actually the Android version is 2.3.5, but then to how much time it can take?

Comment: @NeeleshPandey: I am not aware of that. But keep it connected to WiFi/3G/GPRS. It should happen as soon as your Android Market detects there is an update.

Comment: Yes Sure, I will connect it with WiFi, and will check

Comment: Sometimes it also helps just to open the app and trying to install something. As the "market" app needs to connect to Google's servers for that, the latter notices it's outdated and might trigger the update (I'm not entirely sure which way this works, but I frequently noticed that auto-updates to Google apps happened when I just updated another app, i.e. used the playstore app).